How to use Jupyter notebook to run Matlab installed on a remote computer
I tried working with Matlab in Jupyter notebook and I loved that. Is it possible to configure Jupyter notebook to use Matlab running on a remote computer and access it in my personal computer?

Do you have ssh access to the computer with matlab?

I can configure the remote computer

Are you using Ubuntu? Which version?

Ubuntu 20.04 lts

@Close voters: This is on topic

There are many methods, here I mention two of them.
SSH
Firstly, you will need SSH access to the remote computer. In case you don't, here is how to configure SSH in the remote computer.
Then, open a terminal in your personal computer and connect to the remote computer with
$ ssh -X username@ip.address.of.remote.computer

Note that ssh -X is necessary to access graphical windows running in remote computer in your personal computer.
It will ask you for password, and after logging in, you can access the terminal of the remote computer.
Run MATLAB with
$ matlab

And it should open the MATLAB window (running in the remote computer) in your personal computer.
Alternatively, to run Jupyter, first configure Jupyter with MATLAB in the remote computer. Then, run the following command after signing in with SSH,
$ jupyter notebook

This will open a jupyter notebook interface in your personal computer. Now configure the MATLAB kernel to access MATLAB with jupyter.
VNC
You can install RealVNC server in your remote computer, and install RealVNC viewer in your personal computer.
Then, sign in to both computers with the same account. Afterward, you can use RealVNC viewer in your personal computer to access the desktop of your remote computer (and run Jupyter with MATLAB there).
(Note: You can use other VNC clients, but there you need to manually set up the IP address to connect. With RealVNC, you can just sign in with your email and a password, and for personal usage, it is free for upto three computers).
Rustdesk
If you use RealVNC (a proprietary software), your information will be relayed through their servers. If you want to use your own server, then use Rustdesk instead. It is a free and open source software.

Thnx, do you think working like this is easy and comfortable?

Easy - Yes, once you set it up. Is it comfortable? That is something only you can try and decide.

Thnx, Is it possible to use local jupyter installation instead of access it remotely?

@born2code I don't think MATLAB has that feature. Possible with Python and Julia Jupyter notebooks though
